# Using diagbox package alters text font in JASSS Latex Template

Tags: diagbox

I am using `\diagbox` package to format tables using [JASSS template] (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/jasss-article-template/pnrdvncxsjmn). However, upon using it the font type, size and colour in the entire document, change. The list of packages I use are as below.

```
\documentclass{JASSS}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[original]{pict2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{ragged2e, eqparbox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\norm[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\definecolor{linkcolor}{rgb}{0,0,0.4}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}m{#1} <{\hspace*{-1pt}}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2010}{-}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\diagbox[trim=l,height=3\line]{\small\textbf{A\& B}}{\small\strut \textbf{C}}}& \textbf{D} & \textbf{E}\\
\end{tabular}
\label{table2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Would be helpful to learn how to fix this problem. The font appears as in the image.[altered text font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Rwg.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Rwg.png)

Comment: I see no font change with or without `diagbox`.

Comment: That is really strange. When I try it, the font changes and the table disappears. A snapshot of how the text looks is now included with the question.

Comment: Your code raises many errors; first remove them.

Answer (score 1):

The following MWE reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass{JASSS}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\begin{document}
\parano{}
\section{Section title}
Some text in the section

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\diagbox[trim=l,height=3\line]{\small\textbf{A\& B}}{\small\strut \textbf{C}}}& \textbf{D} & \textbf{E}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\section{New section}
some more text\par
extra paragraph\par
and a third
\endparano

\end{document}
```

The issue is that the JASSS class redefines the macro for displaying the section number (`\thesection`) to reset the counter that the class uses for displaying a number in front of each paragraph. The `diagbox` package loads the `calc` package, and `calc` does not handle this kind of counter reset properly - or alternatively you can say that JASSS does not handle the `calc` package properly.

The following line in `JASSS.cls` causes the problem:

```
% line 246
\renewcommand\thesection{\setcounter{parano}{0}}
```

To solve the issue you can reset the paragraph numbers in a different way, using `\@addtoreset`. Then you can provide a new redefinition of `\thesection` that does nothing, which has the effect of removing the section number (which is desired) and not triggering the `calc` error (which is also desired).

MWE of solution:

```
\documentclass{JASSS}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{parano}{section}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\thesection{\relax}
\begin{document}
\parano{}
\section{Section title}
Some text in the section

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\diagbox[trim=l,height=3\line]{\small\textbf{A\& B}}{\small\strut \textbf{C}}}& \textbf{D} & \textbf{E}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\section{New section}
some more text\par
extra paragraph\par
and a third
\endparano

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that I replaced `\toprule` by `\hline` because `\toprule` does not align nicely with `\diagbox`.

---

General note: your question focused on the color and font changes that you observed. However, the real error was the problem with `calc`, which does not have anything to do with the font or color. The reason you see the changes is that Overleaf (and many desktop editors as well) is set to continue after an error. However, in that case the error often causes unrelated issues further down in the code, as you have experienced here. Therefore, this setting in Overleaf is rather unfortunate, because it causes highly misleading behavior such as people thinking that `diagbox` changes colors. The correct way of diagnosing such a problem is, when any error occurs (visible as a red box in Overleaf next to the Recompile button), to *not look at the output* but instead click on the error indicator and read the actual error message of the first error that is reported.

Comment: You can use `\counterwithin*{parano}{section}` instead of `\@addtoreset`…

Comment: @cgnieder doesn't that need an additional package?

Comment: no, it's part of the kernel since 2018, see `texdoc ltnews28`

Comment: @cgnieder good to know, thanks for the comment. I thought the package was still needed after reading the first half of https://texfaq.org/FAQ-addtoreset, that page mentions the 2018 change at the end but I stopped reading by that time :)